# Emoji Keyboard Loading

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Is there a way to load the Emoji keyboard straight away in a gamescene, instead of the usual alphabetic keyboard?

Or is there a way to restrict the alphabetic keyboard and just have the Emoji Keyboard?

Comment: I do not think this is possible,  you can only specify specific keyboard layouts.  Not everybody has the Emoji Keyboard installed, how would you handle those users?

Comment: KnightOfDragon, you are correct. I did not think of this! I will have to rethink my idea. Cheers!